# I can't update input value Directus

Tags: directus

When updating an Input using this.values.input_name = 'some value' from a child component or change by javascript in the child custom component, the new value is displayed correctly in the input on the parent, but not updated on save. If values are changed manually, everything works as expected.

Is there a way to call an onchange event for inputs on the parent component, from the child?
Could you help me?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for updating the input value is:

```
this.$store.dispatch('stageValue', { field: '', value: '' });
```

I can solve this thanks to [this answer](https://github.com/directus/app/issues/2400)